# Changing WS API from Play Framework! 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: web-services, playframework, playframework-2.4, playframework-2.5

With Playframework! 2.5 the result of a WS request is now a `CompletionStage<WSResponse>`.

```
CompletionStage <WSResponse> completionStage = ws.url("http://url/enewsletter/signupAuto.aspx")
            .setRequestTimeout(2500)
            .setQueryParameter("email", user.getEmail())
            .get();
CompletionStage <String> resultPromise = completionStage.thenApply(WSResponse::getBody);

//String result = responsePromise.get(2500).getBody();
String result = ""; // ?????
```

I could easy get the result from the promise in before using the `F.Promise<WSReponse>` but I don't see to get how to get the result with `CompletionStage`. I need the result for processing before continuing the procedure.

The reason I like to have the result is that this function is performed in a 'for' loop gathering information which then is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it in:

```
completionStage.toCompletableFuture();
```

Comment: There's a general migration guide here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaMigration25 and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html has notes in the deprecation showing which methods to use.